# how to create the quintile column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have [a credit card default dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/default-of-credit-card-clients-dataset), and I want to sort the sorting the AMT_BILL1-6 into Quintiles in order to use them in the decision tree, how can I do it? ,
I tried `Groupby` it did not work for me, thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pandas.qcut()` does what (I think) you are looking for. It operates on a series, so feed it each column and it will return categories and bins. Manual page is [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.qcut.html). You can choose how you apply it to each column (using `df.itercolumns()` or `df.apply()` for example)